# How long are the life phases of a dragon?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons, aging

The life phases of a dragon in 5th edition D&D are:

- Egg
- Wyrmling
- Young
- Adult
- Ancient

Given that a dragon lives for at the least 15-ish centuries, up to I think well over two thousand years, how long does each phase of their life last?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> **Dragon Age Categories**
>
> - Wyrmling (5 years or less)
> - Young (6-100 years)
> - Adult (101-800 years)
> - Ancient (801 years or more)

From 5e MM p.86

Comment: As of this comment, the addition of the Greatwyrm has been made via Fizban's Treasury of Dragons. The age for Chromatic Greatwyrms is around 1200 years. It might be assumed that Gem and Metallic follow a similar aging path, though that is not specified. What IS specified is that all three types appear to merge their echoes across planes into one near-godlike form.

Answer (score 8):

While [Samuel Kelley's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/113321/52137) covers for 5e matertial, 3.5e breaks it down further:

| Dragon | min-max | Human | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wyrmling | 0-5 | 0 - 2 |  |
| Very Young | 6-15 | 2 - 6 |  |
| Young | 16-25 | 6 - 10 |  |
| Juvenile | 26-50 | 10 - 15 |  |
| Young Adult | 50-100 | 15 - 20 | Age that eggs may be produced |
| Adult | 101-200 | 20 - 30 |  |
| Mature Adult | 201-400 | 30 - 40 |  |
| Old | 401-600 | 40 - 55 |  |
| Very Old | 601-800 | 55 - 70 |  |
| Ancient | 801-1000 | 70 - 80 | Female egg laying usually ends |
| Wyrm | 1001-1200 | 80 - 90 |  |
| Great Wyrm | 1201-4400 | 90+ |  |

- It is noted in the Draconomicon that each dragon has a maximum age before the period of "Twilight" when rapid deterioration occurs. Whites die at the earliest around 2100 years while Gold dragons live to be the longest at about 4400 years (Dragonomicon: pages 10 - 15)
- Most of this comes from the Dragonomicons (relating to age and approximate human equivalents) and their explanation of the twilight period, as well as the Monster Manuals

Comment: And to complete rubik's welcome: Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Good info, just note that there has (so far) been no publication of Dragonomicon for 5e, so while this information can be taken as "D&D lore", it may not apply to 5e.