# Is there a way to mature my dragon faster?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons, aging

Recently, in D&D 5e game, I got a young dragon and I want it to become at least mature (if ancient is not a possibility). However, I wouldn't like to wait for too long. Is there some kind of potion/spell that can speed this process up or some other way?

The campaign won't last a year, so my dragon cannot wait 100 years to mature.

Comment: Related on [Scaring a wyrmling into adulthood](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131636/scaring-a-wyrmling-into-adulthood)

Comment: Related: [How long are the life phases of a dragon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113308/how-long-are-the-life-phases-of-a-dragon)

Answer (score 23):

## Depends on what you call "mature".

Raw aging can be done via magical means, as accurately described in [K-T's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139368/is-there-a-way-to-mature-my-dragon-faster/139371#139371).

But an [adult dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/adult-gold-dragon) has a better stat block than a [young dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/young-gold-dragon) not only because of its age, but also because of its experience (and growth, which may be treated separately from aging by your DM - as [concluded here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131636/scaring-a-wyrmling-into-adulthood)).

**Your DM will decide what stat block he wants to use for a "magically aged young dragon"** - and how the creature behaves, depending on the chosen method.

By the way, he will also decide whether a *tamed adult* dragon fits his campaign - which may render your project anywhere from *easy* to *painful* to *impossible*.

Comment: As a DM I would also take it into consideration if the PC subjected the dragon to psycological torture.

Comment: I can't imagine a dragon would be very fond of you if you aged it up by repeatedly torturing it with a ghost's horrifying visage.

Answer (score 15):

## Lots of Potions of Longevity

> **Potion of Longevity**
>
> *Potion, very rare*
>
> When you drink this potion, your physical age is reduced by 1d6 + 6
>   years, to a minimum of 13 years. Each time you subsequently drink a
>   potion of longevity, there is 10 percent cumulative chance that you
>   instead age by 1d6 + 6 years. Suspended in this amber liquid are a
>   scorpion's tail, an adder's fang, a dead spider, and a tiny heart
>   that, against all reason, is still beating. These ingredients vanish
>   when the potion is opened.

The first few times the dragon drinks the potion, it'll probably get younger. But after the 10th potion, the dragon will be guaranteed to get older every time. Getting enough Potions of Longevity might be tough though, due to them being very rare.

Alternatively...

## Get a ghost to scare your dragon

Consider the ghost's Horrifying Visage action:

> **Horrifying Visage.** Each non-undead creature within 60 ft. of the ghost
>   that can see it must succeed on a DC 13 Wisdom saving throw or be
>   frightened for 1 minute. If the save fails by 5 or more, the target
>   also ages 1d4 x 10 years. A frightened target can repeat the saving
>   throw at the end of each of its turns, ending the Frightened condition
>   on itself on a success. If a target's saving throw is successful or
>   the effect ends for it, the target is immune to this ghost's
>   Horrifying Visage for the next 24 hours. The aging effect can be
>   reversed with a Greater Restoration spell, but only within 24 hours of
>   it occurring.

If the ghost uses this action, and the dragon's Wisdom saving throw is 8 or below, it will age an average of 25 years. A ghost can try to scare the dragon once every 24 hours. That might not be very quick compared to drinking a bunch of potions, but it's a lot cheaper!

Comment: OP asks about how to "mature" the dragon into a more powerful dragon (not how to age it into an older one only). Can you explain clearly how your solutions about aging translate into maturation?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Even though the "scaring a wyrmling"'s most upvoted answer clearly distinguished the 2, I feel they may some room for dm's fiat in such situation. I can't see a fundamental difference between growth and senescence - and if you isolate them both from "aging", it kind of renders the Potion of Longevity pointless.

Answer (score 14):

### Honestly, there's not much time or age manipulation available in DnD 5e.

Probably because time is one of the biggest headaches for any GM of any game to deal with, especially on the small scale, where you could use even a half-second of time manipulation to reroll a bad roll, undo an enemy's action, cast multiple spells in one turn, or any number of other crazy things. A Time Turner in DnD would be a Deity-level artifact. I'd never put one in my game, tbh.

But, there are some options not already covered:

- **You could cast Wish and use it to age your dragon.**  This is subject to the risk the DM will mess with you for using Wish outside its standard parameters.
- **Polymorph might work, DM willing.**
- **Find a plane with much faster time than the material plane.** Maybe
  make a deal with an Archfey to bring your dragon into his realm for a
  century or two of his time, while only a few weeks pass for you.

Honestly, this would probably be my favorite option as a DM because
it is story driven and not just a mechanical trick requiring
adjudication.

### But why do this?

You might want to ask why you want an Adult dragon pet. It'll have a solid chance to be smarter than you depending on stats, much stronger, and entirely free-willed with no reason to obey or serve you. Even the Good-aligned dragons have a towering ego and lots of pride. It may not go as well for you as you think, and no GM is going to give players an overwhelming power advantage that will let them steamroll the game. An Adult dragon gets Legendary Actions and Legendary Resistance, and allowing Players to control those on any kind of regular basis is a huge balance problem.

Comment: I know of planes that progress slower, but what planes progress faster than the Material in 5e lore?

Comment: @NautArch The Feywild has a Time Warp (DMG 50) table that can turn days into various amounts of time, including minutes or hours, which would mean that the creature's time progressed faster than on the material plane. It is random, though, so no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

The 9th level spell time ravage brings a character to nearly die of old age.  That would technically make him an ancient dragon, but being near death would make him next to useless.

Combine this with a potion of longevity and you will have an ancient dragon for at least the year you have left in your campaign.

However, you should consider that this is very evil to shorten a dragons lifespan just to gain power for a short time.  It is very likely that the dragon will no longer be your friend after this.  If it is a metalic dragon then it would be seen as a very evil deed to do this to such a symbol of goodness.

Comment: A quick google search reveals that this from the chronurgy wizard's expanded spell list from Explorer's Guide to Wildemount. A citation like that will really improve this answer.