# Giving my players a dragon

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons

I'm starting a new campaign and I was thinking of giving my players a newly hatched baby dragon in the start of the campaign. I think it would be cool if when it's grown a bit that they can have it as a mount/"pet" but it'll probably be a bit overpowered. What are your thoughts on the idea and do you have any suggestions on how I could maybe nerf the dragon not to make it super over powered to have a dragon as a pet (they would be around 4th level when they get the dragon and it wouldn't be grown enough to ride or use in combat until maybe 8-10th level).

The setting for the campaign is a world I've created hence why if I go with giving them a dragon I'll  homebrew it so that dragons mature a lot quicker and I'll just motivate it with some of the other weird stuff that happens in the world. So yeah I'm aware that it would otherwise take a few hundred years to mature.

Comment: Keep in mind that dragons are intelligent beings, and most of them are as smart as adult humans from the moment they hatch.

Comment: Hi and welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. This is a very vague/broad question; "What are your thoughts"-type questions aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format, and may be [better suited to a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). If you can edit your question to narrow it down a bit on exactly what you're asking, we might be better able to answer it.

Comment: Are your players going to be spending 200+ years from level 4 to 8-10?

Comment: @Theik According to [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/113321/35259), it would only be about 5 years, assuming we're going from Wyrmling ("baby") to Young (Large creature, i.e. a mount)